How do I pack and publish a multi project solution template using azure devops and nuget?
What I have
I have three projects that I want to see in every new greenfield application:



Project
Type
Notes




MyTemplate.API
Web API
Communication with external consumers


MyTemplate.Persistence
EF DB
Database access through EF Core 8


MyTemplate.Domain
Models
A collection of all domain models



I have created a new solution with those 3 projects added in a dummy state, other than a few folders and sample files (similar to the WeatherForeCast info you get with a Web API).
Using Project > Export Template in Visual Studio for each of those projects I get a collection of zip files.
I move those out of my Output location and add a general .vstemplate file (incl. an icon):
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>My Solution Template</Name>
        <Description>A solution template for custom application</Description>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
        <ProjectSubType>
        </ProjectSubType>
        <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
        <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
        <DefaultName>My Solution</DefaultName>
        <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
        <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
        <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
        <Icon>myIcon.png</Icon>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectCollection>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.API">
                MyTemplate.API\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Persistence">
                MyTemplate.Persistence\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Domain">
                MyTemplate.Domain\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </ProjectCollection>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>

Next I do the following steps

I extract the zip files generated by the Export Template step
Remove the zip files (in my temp folder)
I make sure the icon and .vstemplate files are there
I select all and copy it to the appropriate templates folder on my local system as is

Local template folder corresponds to:
%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates
If I then start my Visual Studio and select Create New Project I can select my solution template and everything seems to be in place.
So far so good.
What's the next step?
I want to automate this relatively laborious process using the Azure Devops pipeline I already have. I have not found information on how to pack and publish a full solution template. So as the subject states ..

How do I pack and publish a multi project solution template using
azure devops and nuget?

I have no idea what to look for, I found mention of packing individual projects but not of a multi-project solution so I have no idea where to look.
Any tips appreciated.

The steps you mentioned are following the doc Create multi-project templates. Did you export the project template and put in the devops repo?  After all done in root template, can compress the root folder into zip and publish as pipeline artifact instead nuget package.

@wadezhou-MSFT I am not sure I understand what you mean, could you please add a proper answer with step by step instructions?

@kbd I posted an answer with the simplest example steps for your reference.  I hope my answer is comprehensive enough for you. By the way, the nuspec example and yaml example I shared is just a simple example, just to tell you roughly how to write it. The core steps are already written in it anyway. In addition, I also shared at the end of the answer which documents beginners should start from to understand various concepts. Those documents are basically the most basic examples. Even without my answer content, you should be able to understand it via the official documents I shared. :)

Since you have already create the template, below is steps for you to refer:
1. Create a NuGet package for the template
You need to create a NuGet package that contains your solution template. This is typically done by creating a .nuspec file that specifies the files to include in the NuGet package.

Create a .nuspec file at the root of your solution. Here's an example of what this file might look like(this is just a demo, just let you know how to use file selection):

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MySolutionTemplate</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>YourName</authors>
    <description>Template for My Solution with API, Persistence, and Domain projects.</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="MyTemplate.API\**\*.*" target="content\MyTemplate.API" />
    <file src="MyTemplate.Persistence\**\*.*" target="content\MyTemplate.Persistence" />
    <file src="MyTemplate.Domain\**\*.*" target="content\MyTemplate.Domain" />
    <file src="*.vstemplate" target="content" />
  </files>
</package>

2. Set up the Azure DevOps Pipeline
Create a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps to automate the building, packaging, and publishing of your solution template.

Create a new YAML build pipeline:

Go to Pipelines in Azure DevOps, then select "New pipeline".
Choose where your code is hosted (e.g., Azure Repos Git).
Select your repository and branch containing the solution template.


Define the steps in your YAML file. Here’s an example pipeline configuration(this is also a demo, your side maybe a bit different):
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.nuspec'
    packDestination: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'YourFeedId'

This pipeline installs NuGet, restores dependencies, builds the solution, packages your template into a NuGet package using the .nuspec file, and then pushes it to an Azure Artifacts feed.


3. Run the Pipeline
Once the pipeline is configured, commit your changes to trigger the build (or run it manually from Azure DevOps). Check the pipeline logs to ensure that each step completes successfully and that your package is pushed to the NuGet feed.
4. Use the Template from NuGet
After the package is published to your NuGet feed, you can install and use the template in Visual Studio or through the dotnet new command, depending on your setup and preferences. Make sure to configure your NuGet sources to include your Azure Artifacts feed.
For you to understand more clearly, here share some related official documents to you:
Nuspec reference
Custom template for dotnet new
Create your first pipeline - Azure Pipeline
Publish NuGet packages with Azure Pipelines (YAML/Classic)
